Make the Entire Area of a Canvas Overflow Object Selectable with Fabric.js
I am working on a React project using Fabric.js to render a canvas with some objects that overflow beyond the canvas boundaries. I want to be able to make the entire top-level div containing the canvas selectable, including any part of objects that may be clipped by the canvas.
Essentially, I need to enable dragging to select these overflown areas as well.
Here's my current implementation:
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Canvas, Rect } from 'fabric';

export const Canvas = () => {
  const canvasWrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const fabricCanvasRef = useRef<Canvas | null>(null);

  const resizeCanvas = () => {
    const canvas = fabricCanvasRef.current;
    const container = canvasWrapperRef.current;

    if (canvas && container) {
      const containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
      const ratio = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();

      canvas.setDimensions({
        width: containerWidth,
        height: containerWidth / ratio,
      });

      const scale = containerWidth / canvas.getWidth();
      canvas.setViewportTransform([scale, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) return;

    const fabricCanvas = new Canvas(canvasRef.current, {
      width: 500,
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      height: 500,
    });

    fabricCanvasRef.current = fabricCanvas;

    const rect = new Rect({
      fill: 'royalblue',
      top: -50,
      left: -50,
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
    });

    fabricCanvas.add(rect);

    resizeCanvas();

    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
      fabricCanvas.dispose();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh',
        placeItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          margin: 'auto',
          border: 'solid 1px black',
          height: 500,
          width: 500,
        }}
        ref={canvasWrapperRef}
      >
        <canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Current implementation using Fabric 6
Expected behavior would be(with control handles visible)
